# MySQL and time series boolean status changes

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a time series (in MySQL, though might eventually be in PostgreSQL) table:

```
CREATE TABLE `logging` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recordtime` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `device_on` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

Basically the table logs the "on/off" status of a remote sensor device. There are a few other columns, but they are irrelevant to the question here. Most of the log events occur with a standard 2 minute interval, but this can be variable, there can be gaps, etc. The table is not yet terribly big (just a little over a million years), but will grow fairly consistently going forward!

I'm looking for interesting ways to run a query that can give me the aggregate time spent on (device_in = 'Y') in a given time span. My current solution is decidedly non-optimal and uses Javascript to do calculations on the user side.

As a second (related) question, any suggestions as to how to structure index keys on this table?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but where is your FK to the sensor ID?

Comment: if the sensors is just two-state (on or off), why not having two timestamp columns and tracking just the on state? the query then becomes trivial

Comment: @Declan_K: there is a FK sensor_id that I omitted from the question.

Comment: @guido: Well, there are a handful of other columns that relate to the device status (voltage, battery, etc) that are returned whether or not device_on='Y'. Sorry for not being more clear.